# How do I append an uneven column to an existing one?

Tags: pandas

I am having trouble appending later values from column C to column A within the same df using pandas. I have tried `.append` and `.concat` with `ignore_index=True`, still not working.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'a':[1,2,3,None, None], 'b':[7,8,9, None, None], 'c':[None, None, None, 5, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df['a'] = df['a'].append(df['c'], ignore_index=True)

print(df)

     a    b    c
0  1.0  7.0  NaN
1  2.0  8.0  NaN
2  3.0  9.0  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  5.0
4  NaN  NaN  6.0
```

Desired:

```
     a    b    c
0  1.0  7.0  NaN
1  2.0  8.0  NaN
2  3.0  9.0  NaN
3  5.0  NaN  5.0
4  6.0  NaN  6.0
```

Comment: Please do not post your data as images, it's impossible for me to copy/paste this for testing. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: I can't figure out how to recreate column C with the blank values above.

Comment: Fill them with something like `np.nan`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for updating that, this is what I would do:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].fillna(df['c'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     a    b    c
0  1.0  7.0  NaN
1  2.0  8.0  NaN
2  3.0  9.0  NaN
3  5.0  NaN  5.0
4  6.0  NaN  6.0
```